# How expose data from server to client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new with node.js. I'm writing a single rest API and I want to know what is the right way to expose data without expose unnecessary information.

In my example, I have a "Tag" schema. And I don't want to expose the mongoose fields to my client. My code:

```
apiRoutes.get('/tag', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
}), (req, res) => {
    Tag.find({}, (err, tags) => {
        return res.json(tags);
    });
});
```

But in client, I don't want to expose "_id" and "__v":

```
{
        "_id": "57083a5e725f3cf0242a2916",
        "tagName": "Test",
        "en_us": "Testing",
        "__v": 0,
        "lastUpdated": "2016-04-08T23:10:22.759Z"
    }
```

What is the right way to map only relevant fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can always use mongoose virtuals. Here is an example:

In your model, you can use something like this:

```
Tag
  .virtual('public')
  .get(function() {
    return {
      tagName: this.tagName,
      en_us: this.en_us,
      lastUpdated: this.lastUpdated
    };
  });
```

Then, when making a query, just use the virtual you've created:

```
Tag.find({}, (err, tags) => {
  res.json(tags.map(tag => tag.public));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Schema transform toJSON. Here is a blog post explains it in details [ignore certain fields from mongoose schema when return object to client](https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2015/02/08/ignore-certain-fields-from-mongoose-schema-when-return-object-to-client/)

```
TagSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
    delete ret._id;
    delete ret.__v;
    return ret;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare required fields separated by space in `find` method:

```
Tag.find({}, 'tagName en-us', (err, tags) => {
    return res.json(tags);
});
```

Check [mongoose documenation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).